# Javascript Click Function Return?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, click, return

I have delete button and it pops yes or no buttons.
when I click remove it will show buttons and should bind click to them,after that when user press answers i want return value to first function. Can I do that with just 2-3 functions?

```
function ask(){
    var answer;
    $(".menu-3").transition({
        marginTop: "0px"
    }, 200);
    $("#yes").bind("click", function() { 
        answer = "yes"; 
        return answer;
    });
    $("#no").bind("click", function() { 
        answer = "no"; 
        return answer;
    });
}
$("#delete").click(function(answer){
    var answer = ask();
})
```

Comment: No, this is not  how event handlers work in Javascript.  When you call `ask()`, it installs two event handlers and then it returns.  Those event handlers will be called sometime far into the future.  Meanwhile the `ask()` function has already returned its value.  There is simply no way for one of those event handlers to contribute to the return value of `ask()`.

Comment: how can i do that best way?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are trying to accomplish.  You need to carry out an action in your code when the buttons are clicked, not return a value from the event handler.  Javascript is event driven.  You respond to events and write code that does something in those event handlers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do it like this

```
$("#delete").on("click",function(){
    $(".menu-3").animate({
        marginTop: "0px"
    }, 200);
    $(".buttons").on("click", function() { // give the yes/no a class
        if (this.id=="yes") process(); 
        $(".menu-3").hide(); // remove dialog
    });
})

function process() {
  // here someone clicked yes
}
```